# Always switch from method call

Tags: ruby, performance, optimization, benchmarking, evaluation

I wanted to write a code analyser. I wanted to grab any method called at any time and run a generic méthode with the name of the one first one called in argument.

This New method would initiate a timer and incrément the number Of calls performed. Then I would lauch the initially requested one. Finaly when thé method will bé donné I would count thé Time execution and continue the rest Of execution.

Son 2 questions:

- Is there any existing Benchmark tool that could do that (give the numéro of calls an time exécution method by method).
- Is there anyway to redirect any méthode calme toi a generic method of a code?

Thanks in avance for you appreciated help!

Code Benchmark and get number Of calms

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: [edit] your question to provide more information.  Do not post an answer unless you're actually answering your own question, to help future readers with the same question.